# After groupby, evaluate value in column against column values in all rows in the group

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I am looking for the following functionality in python:

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 4 columns: ID, StartDate, EndDate, Moment.

I want to group by ID and evaluate per row in the group whether the Moment variable falls between the interval between StartDate and EndDate. The problem is that I want to evaluate this for each row in the group. For example in the following DataFrame there are two groups (ID=1 and ID=2) and both groups contains of 5 rows. For each row, I want a boolean for each row in both groups whether the moment variable in that row falls in ANY of the time windows in the group, the window being [date1, date2].

```py
import pandas as pd

i = pd.date_range('2018-04-11', periods=10, freq='2D20min')
i2 = pd.date_range('2018-04-12', periods=10, freq='2D20min')
i3 = pd.date_range('2018-04-9', periods=10, freq='1D6H')
id = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2']
ts = pd.DataFrame({'date1': i, 'date2': i2, 'moment': i3}, index=id)

ID  date1               date2               moment
1   2018-04-11 00:00:00 2018-04-12 00:00:00 2018-04-09 00:00:00
1   2018-04-13 00:20:00 2018-04-14 00:20:00 2018-04-10 06:00:00
1   2018-04-15 00:40:00 2018-04-16 00:40:00 2018-04-11 12:00:00
1   2018-04-17 01:00:00 2018-04-18 01:00:00 2018-04-12 18:00:00
1   2018-04-19 01:20:00 2018-04-20 01:20:00 2018-04-14 00:00:00
2   2018-04-21 01:40:00 2018-04-22 01:40:00 2018-04-15 06:00:00
2   2018-04-23 02:00:00 2018-04-24 02:00:00 2018-04-16 12:00:00
2   2018-04-25 02:20:00 2018-04-26 02:20:00 2018-04-17 18:00:00
2   2018-04-27 02:40:00 2018-04-28 02:40:00 2018-04-19 00:00:00
2   2018-04-29 03:00:00 2018-04-30 03:00:00 2018-04-20 06:00:00
```

In this case, the value for moment in the first row of the first group does not fall in any of the five time intervals. Neither does the second. The third value, `2018-04-11 12:00:00` does fall in the interval in the first row and I would thus want to have `True` returned.

The desired result would look as follows:

```py
ID  date1               date2               moment              result
1   2018-04-11 00:00:00 2018-04-12 00:00:00 2018-04-09 00:00:00 False
1   2018-04-13 00:20:00 2018-04-14 00:20:00 2018-04-10 06:00:00 False
1   2018-04-15 00:40:00 2018-04-16 00:40:00 2018-04-11 12:00:00 True
1   2018-04-17 01:00:00 2018-04-18 01:00:00 2018-04-12 18:00:00 False
1   2018-04-19 01:20:00 2018-04-20 01:20:00 2018-04-14 00:00:00 True
2   2018-04-21 01:40:00 2018-04-22 01:40:00 2018-04-15 06:00:00 False
2   2018-04-23 02:00:00 2018-04-24 02:00:00 2018-04-16 12:00:00 False
2   2018-04-25 02:20:00 2018-04-26 02:20:00 2018-04-17 18:00:00 False
2   2018-04-27 02:40:00 2018-04-28 02:40:00 2018-04-19 00:00:00 False
2   2018-04-29 03:00:00 2018-04-30 03:00:00 2018-04-20 06:00:00 False
```

EDIT

I already 'solved' this problem with the following approach but am looking for a more pythonic and perhaps faster way...

```py
boolean_result = []
for c in ts.index.unique():
    temp = ts.loc[ts.index == c]
    for row in temp.index:
        current_date = temp['moment'][row]
        boolean_result.append(max((temp['date1'] <= current_date)
                                  & (current_date <= temp['date2'])))
ts['Result'] = boolean_result
```

Answer (score 1):

This may actually be very slow if your dataframe is too big, and there might be an optimal solution other than this one:

```
def time_in_range(start, end, x):
    """Return true if x is in the range [start, end]"""
    if start <= x and x <= end:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# empty list to be appended
result = []
test_list = []

for i in ts.index.unique():

    temp_df = ts[ts.index == i]

    for j in range(0, len(temp_df)):
        for k in range(0, len(temp_df)):    
            test_list.append(time_in_range(temp_df.date1.iloc[k], temp_df.date2.iloc[k], temp_df.moment.iloc[j]))

        result.append(any(test_list))
        # reset the list
        test_list = []

ts['result'] = result
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already have a 'working' solution with the same idea which is as follows:
```python
boolean_result = []
for c in ts.index.unique():
    temp = ts.loc[ts.index == c]
    for row in temp.index:
        current_date = temp['moment'][row]
        boolean_result.append(max((temp['date1'] <= current_date)
                                  & (current_date <= temp['date2'])))
ts['Result'] = boolean_result
```

But I'm hoping for a faster more pythonic approach!